# Check whether a string is a date in a specific format, e.g. "%Y-%m-%d"

Tags: regular-expressions, time-date, parsing, format-time-string

I have a string and would like to check whether it contains a date in a given date format, e.g. "%Y-%m-%d", with format as for `format-time-string`.  This is for a package and users can configure the date format freely.  So I cannot just hard-code a regular expression.

Comment: This question is not about `elisp` and I've got the impression that the description of the `time-date` tag fits best. See the description of that tag, it includes handling of date formats.

Comment: https://github.com/doublep/datetime supports Java format like yyyy-MM-dd, but doesn't support Emacs format like %Y-%m-%d.

Comment: Note that for your example format (and many others), the best you could do in general would be to check whether a string *might* be (intended to represent) a date in that format, as it could also be a different date in a different format resulting in the same string.

Comment: FWIW `format-time-string` is using [strftime(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) and (nowadays at least) there seems to be [strptime(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) which does the inverse (which is more or less what you're asking for), so *if* that library call is available everywhere that modern Emacs cares about, this is probably a feature which could be added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `format-time-string` uses the same format as [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html), and [strptime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) is the reverse of strftime(3), so I wrote an Emacs dynamic [module](https://github.com/xuchunyang/strptime.el) just for strptime(3), for example,

```el
(strptime "2020-04-01" "%Y-%m-%d")
;; => (0 0 0 1 4 2020 3 nil 0)
```

The result is `(SEC MINUTE HOUR DAY MONTH YEAR DOW DST UTCOFF)`, you can feed it to `encode-time`

```el
(apply #'encode-time (strptime "2020-04-01" "%Y-%m-%d"))
;; => (24195 55680)

(format-time-string
 "%Y-%m-%d"
 (apply #'encode-time (strptime "2020-04-01" "%Y-%m-%d")))
;; => "2020-04-01"
```

Comment: Excellent!  Could you please contribute this feature upstream to Emacs?

Comment: @phils I am not confident to do that as I don't have much experience in C. Though I would be very happy if I can contribute.

Comment: I see that there's an old bug report https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25112 except it was closed on the basis of `date-to-time` existing (which isn't the same thing, but obviously sufficed for those purposes).

Comment: This is great! I agree with @phils that this should be part of Emacs. I had one patch accepted to Emacs and it was a surprisingly good experience, mainly thanks to Eli Zaretskii who gave me valuable input.

Answer (score 2):

A combination of `regexp-quote` and `format-spec` should help in your case. Especially, `format-spec` works with format specifiers of the format sequences consisting of one `%` character and one letter.

```el
(defun my-format-spec-to-regexp (format)
  "Convert FORMAT with placeholders %Y, %m, and %d into a regexp."
  (format-spec (regexp-quote format)
           '((?Y . "\\(?:[0-9][0-9]\\)\\{1,2\\}")
         (?m . "\\(?:1[012]\\|0?[1-9]\\)")
         (?d . "\\(?:0?[1-9]\\|[12][0-9]\\|3[01]\\)"))))


;; Some test:
(insert (prin1-to-string (my-format-spec-to-regexp "%Y\\%m\\%d")))
"\\(?:[0-9][0-9]\\)\\{1,2\\}\\\\\\(?:1[012]\\|0?[1-9]\\)\\\\\\(?:0?[1-9]\\|[12][0-9]\\|3[01]\\)"
```

Comment: For the benefit of readers who might not be aware of it, please consider adding to this answer that to test whether a given time-date string is in the given input (argument `FORMAT`), you would use `string-match-p`. That info seems to be missing from the Q & A. Thx.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but with this approach one would have to completely reverse-engineer `format-time-string` which is fantastically complex (e.g., locale-dependent). Seems like a major effort and with a lot of room for bugs. Unfortunately, I don't have the resources to do that.